# How to save my drawings in a folder with native react?

Tags: javascript, react-native

I want to save the drawings and notes I make with sketch-canvas in a device folder, but I can not find the form, I do not know how to do it.
I have studied and searched for forms, but I do not know how to apply it to this project.
I do not know if I have to create a module like the  [facebook](http://facebook.github.io/react-native/docs/native-modules-ios.html#content) documentation says

```
import React, { Component } from 'react'
import {
  Platform, 
  StyleSheet,
  Text,
  View,
  Alert,
} from 'react-native'

import RNSketchCanvas from '@terrylinla/react-native-sketch-canvas'

export default class App extends Component {
  render() {
    return (
      <View style={styles.container}>
        <View style={{ flex: 1, flexDirection: 'row' }}>
          <RNSketchCanvas
            containerStyle={{ backgroundColor: 'transparent', flex: 1 }}
            canvasStyle={{ backgroundColor: 'transparent', flex: 1 }}
            defaultStrokeIndex={0}
            defaultStrokeWidth={5}
            closeComponent={<View style={styles.functionButton}><Text style={{color: 'white'}}>Cerrar</Text></View>}
            undoComponent={<View style={styles.functionButton}><Text style={{color: 'white'}}>Deshacer</Text></View>}
            clearComponent={<View style={styles.functionButton}><Text style={{color: 'white'}}>Limpiar</Text></View>}
            eraseComponent={<View style={styles.functionButton}><Text style={{color: 'white'}}>Borrador</Text></View>}
            strokeComponent={color => (
              <View style={[{ backgroundColor: color }, styles.strokeColorButton]} />
            )}
            strokeSelectedComponent={(color, index, changed) => {
              return (
                <View style={[{ backgroundColor: color, borderWidth: 2 }, styles.strokeColorButton]} />
              )
            }}
            strokeWidthComponent={(w) => {
              return (<View style={styles.strokeWidthButton}>
                <View  style={{
                  backgroundColor: 'white', marginHorizontal: 2.5,
                  width: Math.sqrt(w / 3) * 10, height: Math.sqrt(w / 3) * 10, borderRadius: Math.sqrt(w / 3) * 10 / 2
                }} />
              </View>
            )}}
            saveComponent={<View style={styles.functionButton}><Text style={{color: 'white'}}>Save</Text></View>}
            savePreference={() => {
              return {
                folder: 'RNSketchCanvas',
                filename: String(Math.ceil(Math.random() * 100000000)),
                transparent: false,
                imageType: 'png'
              }
            }}
            //onSketchSaved={(success, filePath) => { alert('filePath: ' + filePath); }}
          />
        </View>
      </View>
    )
  }
}

const styles = StyleSheet.create({
  container: {
    flex: 1,
    justifyContent: 'center',

  },
  headerText: {
    fontSize: 5,
    textAlign: "center",
    margin: 10,
    fontWeight: "bold"
  },
  strokeColorButton: {
    marginHorizontal: 2.5, marginVertical: 8, width: 30, height: 30, borderRadius: 15,
  },
  strokeWidthButton: {
    marginHorizontal: 2.5, marginVertical: 8, width: 30, height: 30, borderRadius: 15,
    justifyContent: 'center', alignItems: 'center', backgroundColor: '#39579A'
  },
  functionButton: {
    marginHorizontal: 2.5, marginVertical: 8, height: 30, width: 60,
    backgroundColor: '#39579A', justifyContent: 'center', alignItems: 'center', borderRadius: 5,
  }
})
```

You should not create a database.
In this simple application there is a line that would be used to save, but I do not know how to use it.
I show you the code that I have.
Can you tell me how or where should I start?
***EDIT:***

I think this is the line that I should use to save the created bubbles:

// onSketchSaved = {(success, filePath) => {alert ('filePath:' + filePath); }}

But I do not know how to do it, I do not know what to add to save my drawings on Android

Thank you

Answer (score 2):

From the RNSketchCanvas documentation:

> onSketchSaved (function):
>
> An optional function which accpets 2 arguments success and path. If success is true, image is saved successfully and the saved image path might be in second argument. In Android, image path will always be returned. In iOS, image is saved to camera roll or file system, path will be set to null or image location respectively.

Essentially, you are looking for the filepath where your image is stored.

If the image was stored in the camera roll (path is null) you can use the [CameraRoll api](https://facebook.github.io/react-native/docs/cameraroll#getphotos) to retrieve the image path.

Otherwise, you already have a file path for the image. If you then want to move the image you can make use of the moveFile function within [React Native File System library](https://github.com/itinance/react-native-fs) (or [FileSystem](https://docs.expo.io/versions/latest/sdk/filesystem/) API if you are using Expo) to move the file to a folder of your choosing.

This is untested code but should provide a more tangible example of how this process may look:

```
import React, {Component} from 'react'
import {StyleSheet, Text, View, CameraRoll} from 'react-native'

import RNSketchCanvas from '@terrylinla/react-native-sketch-canvas'
import RNFS from 'react-native-fs';

export default class App extends Component {
    render() {
        return (
            <View style={styles.container}>
                <View style={{ flex: 1, flexDirection: 'row' }}>
                    <RNSketchCanvas
                        containerStyle={{ backgroundColor: 'transparent', flex: 1 }}
                        canvasStyle={{ backgroundColor: 'transparent', flex: 1 }}
                        defaultStrokeIndex={0}
                        defaultStrokeWidth={5}
                        closeComponent={<View style={styles.functionButton}><Text style={{color: 'white'}}>Cerrar</Text></View>}
                        undoComponent={<View style={styles.functionButton}><Text style={{color: 'white'}}>Deshacer</Text></View>}
                        clearComponent={<View style={styles.functionButton}><Text style={{color: 'white'}}>Limpiar</Text></View>}
                        eraseComponent={<View style={styles.functionButton}><Text style={{color: 'white'}}>Borrador</Text></View>}
                        strokeComponent={color => (
                            <View style={[{ backgroundColor: color }, styles.strokeColorButton]} />
                        )}
                        strokeSelectedComponent={(color, index, changed) => {
                            return (
                                <View style={[{ backgroundColor: color, borderWidth: 2 }, styles.strokeColorButton]} />
                            )
                        }}
                        strokeWidthComponent={(w) => {
                            return (<View style={styles.strokeWidthButton}>
                                    <View  style={{
                                        backgroundColor: 'white', marginHorizontal: 2.5,
                                        width: Math.sqrt(w / 3) * 10, height: Math.sqrt(w / 3) * 10, borderRadius: Math.sqrt(w / 3) * 10 / 2
                                    }} />
                                </View>
                            )}}
                        saveComponent={<View style={styles.functionButton}><Text style={{color: 'white'}}>Save</Text></View>}
                        savePreference={() => {
                            return {
                                folder: 'RNSketchCanvas',
                                filename: String(Math.ceil(Math.random() * 100000000)),
                                transparent: false,
                                imageType: 'png'
                            }
                        }}
                        onSketchSaved={this.onSave}
                    />
                </View>
            </View>
        )
    }

    onSave = async (success, path) => {
        if(!success) return;
        let imageUri;
        const myNewImagePath = RNFS.DocumentDirectoryPath + 'my_folder'

        try{
            if(path == null){
                // image has been saved to the camera roll
                // Here I am assuming that the most recent photo in the camera roll is the saved image, you may want to check the filename
                const images = await CameraRoll.getPhotos({first: 1});
                if(images.length > 0){
                    imageUri = [0].image.uri;
                }else{
                    console.log('Image path missing and no images in camera roll')
                    return;
                }

            } else{
                imageUri = path
            }

            await RNFS.moveFile(imageUri, myNewImagePath)
        } catch (e) {
            console.log(e.message)
        }
    }
}

const styles = StyleSheet.create({
    container: {
        flex: 1,
        justifyContent: 'center',

    },
    headerText: {
        fontSize: 5,
        textAlign: "center",
        margin: 10,
        fontWeight: "bold"
    },
    strokeColorButton: {
        marginHorizontal: 2.5, marginVertical: 8, width: 30, height: 30, borderRadius: 15,
    },
    strokeWidthButton: {
        marginHorizontal: 2.5, marginVertical: 8, width: 30, height: 30, borderRadius: 15,
        justifyContent: 'center', alignItems: 'center', backgroundColor: '#39579A'
    },
    functionButton: {
        marginHorizontal: 2.5, marginVertical: 8, height: 30, width: 60,
        backgroundColor: '#39579A', justifyContent: 'center', alignItems: 'center', borderRadius: 5,
    }
})
```

Comment: Thank you for your contribution @CampbellMG but it is not clear to me what code I should add. I have edited the question, but I do not know the code that I must add to save the created drawings, since I do not use the camera, I just want to save the drawings made. Can you help me with the code? I have read the documentation offered but I do not know how to use it. Thank you

Comment: I have updated my answer with an example, does this clarify the process? It may also be worth noting that this function is called whenever you click the button rendered from your saveComponent prop.